# Should the name of the main character in "Fate Kaleid Liner" be "Illya" or "Ilya"?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-kaleid-liner-prisma-illya

As the title says, I'm looking for the correct way of spelling her name. Additionally, it would also be appreciated if the general translation for names is explained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Both "Ilya" and "Illya" are official spellings of her nickname. "Ilya" is used on the TYPE-MOON's official website and in the fan translation of the game, but "Illya" tends to be used elsewhere, especially in merchandise.

[Illyasviel von Einzbern Wikia Page: Citation 3](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Illyasviel_von_Einzbern#cite_note-2)